# Why is there some kind of warped paper in my Blender rendering?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, displacement, hdri

[image]

So I was working on my blender project when I realized wraped paper in my render. How I supposed to get rid of it? (It only appear in render and viewport shading)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots I wonder why you prefer PasteAll over blend exchange... Though to be honest blend exchange never worked for me, however small the file be (except of one unique occasion)

Comment: @Yousuf Chaudhry blend exchange works, maybe you miss one of the steps? I prefer to cite pasteall because i've been said once that we must not load too much on blend exchange

Comment: @moonboots I guess that's exactly the problem at my end... Blend exchange just doesn't load, I tried leaving a 4MB file on upload for an hour and no luck. The bar just remained blank.

Comment: @Yousuf Chaudhry in blend exchange, you need to copy paste the URL of the page where the question has been asked. There's a size limit but I guess it's not your problem here

Comment: @moonboots the link needed to be copy-pasted to upload it to the question... However, the files just refused to upload to blend-exchange itself. I guess maybe I just do it at the wrong time.

Answer (score 2):

It's not any kind of warped paper. Looks like you have some real displacement going on on your materials, decrease the scale value on the displacement **node** in your material and this over displacement issue will be fixed. If that's not the case, kindly make sure to share your blender file so we can have a deeper look, though I'm pretty sure that this is a displacement problem.